# Selective Groupby-Aggregate using Python Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate, ohlc

How can we aggregate all the rows after 4pm of one day till before 10am of the next day in the DataFrame by performing OHLC operations on the grouped rows?

This will convert the original DataFrame from

```
   symbol          datetime  open  high  low  close   date  toCombine
0    AAPL  2020-01-01 15:00     3     5    2      4  2020-01-01      False
1    AAPL  2020-01-01 15:30     4    10    4      8  2020-01-01      False
2    AAPL  2020-01-01 16:00     8    15    6     12  2020-01-01      False
3    AAPL  2020-01-01 18:00    12    20    8     16  2020-01-01       True
4    AAPL  2020-01-01 20:00    12    20    8     16  2020-01-01       True
5    AAPL  2020-01-02 07:00    15    24    9     19  2020-01-02       True
6    AAPL  2020-01-02 10:00    16    25   10     20  2020-01-02       True
7    AAPL  2020-01-02 12:00    20    30   12     24  2020-01-02      False
8    AAPL  2020-01-02 14:00    24    70   14     26  2020-01-02      False
9    AAPL  2020-01-02 16:00   103   105  102    104  2020-01-02      False
10   AAPL  2020-01-02 18:00   104   100  104    196  2020-01-02       True
11   AAPL  2020-01-03 08:00   108   110  106    112  2020-01-03       True
12   AAPL  2020-01-03 10:30   112   120  108    116  2020-01-03      False
13   AAPL  2020-01-03 13:00   115   124  109    119  2020-01-03      False
```

to *(ignoring the index values here)*:

```
   symbol          datetime  open  high  low  close   date  
0    AAPL  2020-01-01 15:00     3     5    2      4  2020-01-01      
1    AAPL  2020-01-01 15:30     4    10    4      8  2020-01-01      
2    AAPL  2020-01-01 16:00     8    15    6     12  2020-01-01      
6    AAPL  2020-01-02 10:00    12    25    8     20  2020-01-02  <---- aggregated row    
7    AAPL  2020-01-02 12:00    20    30   12     24  2020-01-02      
8    AAPL  2020-01-02 14:00    24    70   14     26  2020-01-02
9    AAPL  2020-01-02 16:00   103   105  102    104  2020-01-02 
11   AAPL  2020-01-03 10:00   103   110  100    112  2020-01-03  <---- aggregated 10:00 row created if not exist
12   AAPL  2020-01-03 10:30   112   120  108    116  2020-01-03
13   AAPL  2020-01-03 13:00   115   124  109    119  2020-01-03
```

Notes:

1. `toCombine` column has already been created to label the rows that will be aggregated into a single row with `datetime` value that has a time of `10:00`.
2. If the row with a `datetime` value with time of `10:00` does not exist, it should be created. However, if there are also no rows with `toCombine == True` to aggregate from, then the `10:00` row does not need to be created.

Thank you!

---

**Python Code to Setup Problem**

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    ('AAPL', '2020-01-01 15:00', 3, 5, 2, 4, '2020-01-01', False),
    ('AAPL', '2020-01-01 15:30', 4, 10, 4, 8, '2020-01-01', False),
    ('AAPL', '2020-01-01 16:00', 8, 15, 6, 12, '2020-01-01', False),
    ('AAPL', '2020-01-01 18:00', 12, 20, 8, 16, '2020-01-01', True),        
    ('AAPL', '2020-01-01 20:00', 12, 20, 8, 16, '2020-01-01', True),        
    ('AAPL', '2020-01-02 07:00', 15, 24, 9, 19, '2020-01-02', True),       
    ('AAPL', '2020-01-02 10:00', 16, 25, 10, 20, '2020-01-02', True),
    ('AAPL', '2020-01-02 12:00', 20, 30, 12, 24, '2020-01-02', False),
    ('AAPL', '2020-01-02 14:00', 24, 70, 14, 26, '2020-01-02', False),
    ('AAPL', '2020-01-02 16:00', 103, 105, 102, 104, '2020-01-02', False),
    ('AAPL', '2020-01-02 18:00', 104, 100, 104, 196, '2020-01-02', True),     
    ('AAPL', '2020-01-03 08:00', 108, 110, 106, 112, '2020-01-03', True),    
    ('AAPL', '2020-01-03 10:30', 112, 120, 108, 116, '2020-01-03', False),     
    ('AAPL', '2020-01-03 13:00', 115, 124, 109, 119, '2020-01-03', False),     
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['symbol', 'datetime', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'date', 'toCombine'])
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

**My approach**

```
#Group and agg
m = df['toCombine']
agg_dict = {'datetime' : 'last',
            'open' : 'first',
            'high' : 'max',
            'low' : 'min',
            'close' : 'last'}

reduce_df = (df.loc[m].groupby(['symbol',(~m).cumsum()],
                                             as_index=False).agg(agg_dict))
print(reduce_df)

  symbol          datetime  open  high  low  close
0   AAPL  2020-01-02 10:00    12    25    8     20
1   AAPL  2020-01-03 08:00   104   110  104    112
```

group by symbol maybe not neccesary if sorted correctly

---

```
#get correct datetime, append and sort
datetime = pd.to_datetime(reduce_df['datetime'])
hours = datetime.dt.hour
df = (reduce_df.assign(datetime = (datetime.mask(hours.gt(16),
                                        datetime.add(pd.to_timedelta(10 + 24 - hours,
                                        unit='h')))
                                 .mask(hours.lt(10),
                                       datetime.add(pd.to_timedelta(10 - hours,
                                                                    unit='h')))),            
                 date = lambda x: x['datetime'].dt.date)
          .assign(datetime = lambda x: x['datetime'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'))
          .append(df.loc[~m])
          .drop(columns='toCombine')
          .sort_values(['symbol','datetime','date'])
)

print(df)



   symbol          datetime  open  high  low  close        date
0    AAPL  2020-01-01 15:00     3     5    2      4  2020-01-01
1    AAPL  2020-01-01 15:30     4    10    4      8  2020-01-01
2    AAPL  2020-01-01 16:00     8    15    6     12  2020-01-01
0    AAPL  2020-01-02 10:00    12    25    8     20  2020-01-02
7    AAPL  2020-01-02 12:00    20    30   12     24  2020-01-02
8    AAPL  2020-01-02 14:00    24    70   14     26  2020-01-02
9    AAPL  2020-01-02 16:00   103   105  102    104  2020-01-02
1    AAPL  2020-01-03 10:00   104   110  104    112  2020-01-03
12   AAPL  2020-01-03 10:30   112   120  108    116  2020-01-03
```

---

We could have used `dataframe.set_index` and `dataframe.asfreq` and `ffill` previously to groupby so we don't have to change datetime later, but I think the performance will be similar

if you want include hour=16 you need change `datetime.mask(hours.`**ge**`(16).......`

and when we use `.loc` include it, because it is not included by `toCombine`(**row 9 False**)

Comment: I have not caught when the hour is 16 because it had false, but we could include it by changing the mask or the  toCombine